How to find the average sales for particular window period even if some rows are missing
I want to find the average sales of last 4 weeks in Spark SQL for items.



item
Week Num
Sales




1
202401
4


1
202402
6


1
202403
2


1
202404
6


2
202401
4


2
202407
1


2
202408
1


3
202401
8



I want Data like -



item
week_num
sales
Avg_sales_4_weeks




1
202401
4
1


1
202402
6
2.5


1
202403
2
3


1
202404
6
4.5


2
202401
4
1


2
202407
1
0.25


2
202408
1
0.5


3
202401
8
2



I am using the following query to find the average which is giving correct avg if all the consecutive week numbers are present in the table for some particular item but if cosecutive week numbers are not present (In above data example for item number 2 there is no week between 202401 and 202407 so with following query the window function will use week 202401 to calculate the avg even for week 202408 but I don't want that because technically in week 202408 the last 4 week avg would come from 202405 to 202408). So if in some weeks sales is not there it should be used in calculating the avg.
select *, avg(sales) over 
  (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY week_num DESC ROWS BETWEEN current row 
  and 3 following ) as Avg_sales_4_weeks

I can explode the data and insert the weeks with 0 sales but if there is some other way to do that without increasing the number of records.

you need to generate a table that holds all weeks and left join it so that you have a result table witha all weeks

@nbk I can do that but any other way without increasing the number of rows.

@ShunsuiKyoraku Do you have to perform average on 4 weeks periods that overlapping two years. For instance, average sales on those 4 weeks : 202351, 202352, 202401, 202402 ?

@VincentDoba Yes but I can handle that case using some clause

You can use RANGE BETWEEN instead of ROWS BETWEEN when computing the average of the last four weeks. Instead of determining a number of rows, you then use an offset, so it will exclude the rows that are not in your offset.
As the number of rows in each window is not the same anymore, you can't use directly the avg aggregate function. You will have to sum sales column and divide the result by 4.
So you can use the following request:
select *, sum(sales) over 
  (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY week_num ASC RANGE BETWEEN 4 preceding
   and 0 following ) / 4 as Avg_sales_4_weeks

With your example input, you get the following result:
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|item|week_num|sales|Avg_sales_4_weeks|
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|1   |202401  |4    |1.0              |
|1   |202402  |6    |2.5              |
|1   |202403  |2    |3.0              |
|1   |202404  |6    |4.5              |
|2   |202401  |4    |1.0              |
|2   |202407  |1    |0.25             |
|2   |202408  |1    |0.5              |
|3   |202401  |8    |2.0              |
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+

However, this method will not work if you have to compute average for 4 weeks period overlapping two years. For instance if you have the following dataset:
+----+--------+-----+
|item|week_num|sales|
+----+--------+-----+
|4   |202351  |1    |
|4   |202352  |1    |
|4   |202401  |2    |
+----+--------+-----+

You will get the following result:
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|item|week_num|sales|Avg_sales_4_weeks|
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|4   |202351  |1    |0.25             |
|4   |202352  |1    |0.5              |
|4   |202401  |2    |0.5              |
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+

Instead of
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|item|week_num|sales|Avg_sales_4_weeks|
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|4   |202351  |1    |0.25             |
|4   |202352  |1    |0.5              |
|4   |202401  |2    |1.0              |
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+

A solution would be to transform week_num column into timestamp and to perform the range in number of second, but in this case you need to setup date parsing to legacy mode:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

You can then use the following request:
select *, sum(sales) over
  (PARTITION BY item 
   ORDER BY unix_timestamp(to_date(6000000+week_num, 'uyyyyww')) ASC 
   RANGE BETWEEN 4*7*24*3600 preceding and 0 following ) / 4 as Avg_sales_4_weeks

to get the following result:
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|item|week_num|sales|Avg_sales_4_weeks|
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+
|4   |202351  |1    |0.25             |
|4   |202352  |1    |0.5              |
|4   |202401  |2    |1.0              |
+----+--------+-----+-----------------+

